# How to detect if "you" is plural or singular?

Tags: hebrew

I'm a computer programmer and I'm trying to automatically detect if a "you" in the Bible is singular or plural.

First of all, does anybody have a quick, easy answer for me?

If not, I've found a spreadsheet from the Berean Bible website
called [BSB Translation Tables - xlsx](https://berean.bible/downloads.htm)

It looks like this:

| Line | Hebrew | Transliteration | Parsing Code | Parsing Description | English |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | זֹ֣את | zōṯ | Pro-fs | Pronoun - feminine singular | This |
| 2 | בְּרִיתִ֞י | bə·rî·ṯî | N-fsc , 1cs | Noun - feminine singular construct , first person common singular | is My covenant |
| 3 | בֵּינִי֙ | bê·nî | Prep , 1cs | Preposition , first person common singular | with |
| 4 | וּבֵ֣ינֵיכֶ֔ם | ū·ḇê·nê·ḵem | Conj-w , Prep, 2mp | Conjunctive waw , Preposition , second person masculine plural | . . . |
| 5 | וּבֵ֥ין | ū·ḇên | Conj-w , Prep | Conjunctive waw , Preposition | . . . |
| 6 | זַרְעֲךָ֖ | zar·‘ă·ḵā | N-msc , 2ms | Noun - masculine singular construct , second person masculine singular | you and your descendants |
| 7 | אַחֲרֶ֑יךָ | ’a·ḥă·re·ḵā | Prep , 2ms | Preposition , second person masculine singular | after you , |
| 8 | אֲשֶׁ֣ר | ’ă·šer | Pro-r | Pronoun - relative | which |
| 9 | תִּשְׁמְר֗וּ | tiš·mə·rū | V-Qal-Imperf-2mp | Verb - Qal - Imperfect - second person masculine plural | you are to keep : |
| 10 | כָּל־ | kāl- | N-msc | Noun - masculine singular construct | Every |
| 11 | זָכָֽר׃ | zā·ḵār | N-ms | Noun - masculine singular | male among you |
| 12 | הִמּ֥וֹל | him·mō·wl | V-Nifal-InfAbs | Verb - Nifal - Infinitive absolute | must be circumcised . |
| 13 | לָכֶ֖ם | lā·ḵem | Prep , 2mp | Preposition , second person masculine plural |  |

This is Genesis 17:10.

I was thinking I could detect a plural this way:

- Look in the "English" column for the word "you" or "your" or similar.
- Then look in the "Parsing Description" for "second person masculine plural" (or feminine).
- If I detect the plural, that "you" is a plural "you". Otherwise, it's singular.

I think this plan works correctly for lines 6, 7, and 9. But what about line 11?

I think this process will lead to wrong results for the "you" on line 11, which would result in "singular", but I think it's actually "plural."

Am I right?

Can somebody who knows Hebrew give me some advice?

Or maybe this is just impossible without a human checking everything.

Comment: The “among you” part of row 11 actually belongs in row 13 (לָכֶם), hence the missing English in row 13. In Hebrew, the English “you” can be translated from Hebrew pronouns, pronominal suffixes (attached at the end of nouns, verbs, etc.), as well as from verbs which conjugate according to person, gender, number (similar to Spanish), and aspect. Not as easy as it seems to accomplish the task you want, especially when you're relying on tables produced by other individuals (which means you have to verify the accuracy of their product first, and then product your product).

Comment: I suggest you consult a good Hebrew grammar and lexicon.

Comment: Unless you are using a word-for-word translation of the Hebrew, your efforts may be in vain. As for the BSB verse, first, it puts the Hebrew out of correct order. Second, it is not a word-for-word translation. It also adds words that are not in the Hebrew without indicating such -- in Line 11, there is no "among you" in the Hebrew; it is simply 'zakar,' which means 'male.' I can't see any usefulness in this Hebrew/English 'table' for any study or project.  I do have a suggestion where you can see the problems with this BSB 'table' for yourself. See next comment.

Comment: scripture4all.org  Download ISA-2 (Interlinear Scripture Analyzer). It's free. The link can be found in the paragraph above the download for ISA-3 beta. The search feature will not work for the plural 'you' in ISA-3. The flashlight symbol is 'search'.  Under "Interlinear" search, put -- you(p) -- in the CHES line.  Also, just looking at Gen. 10:17, you will see the correct order of the Hebrew and word-for-word translation. Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: Just curious. How is this question closed with only two votes? Info says it takes 5 votes. I have over 500 points, so "List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege." New rules?